# Reading CSV files without providing directory path does not work

Tags: python-3.x, csv, path, pyinstaller, reader

```
def readcsv(myfile):
    myfile_o = open(myfile, "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(myfile_o, delimiter=",")

def csvmain():
    readcsv('/Users/madrad/Dnl/Hei/demand.csv')

csvmain()
```

Why do I need to specify the full path of the csv file I am passing to a function? The path is not needed when I execute the same code in the terminal manually. But, when the code is run as an exe file (compiled using pyinstaller), it does not work without the full path.
Even if I put the csv file in the same directory of the exe file, it does not locate the file and program terminates.
I need the path to be passed programmatically, but I don't know how.  I'd appreciate any suggestions, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) package to normalize and get the absolute path of the file.

```
import os

def readcsv(myfile):
    myfile_o = open(myfile, "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(myfile_o, delimiter=",")

def csvmain():
    readcsv(os.path.normpath(os.path.realpath('/Users/madrad/Dnl/Hei/demand.csv')))

csvmain()
```

I think that with something like this, it should work. I do the same to get a configuration file in different paths and os.

Comment: Thanks. However I was wondering why a simple readcsv('demand.csv') won't work. CSV resides in the same path as my py or exe file.

Comment: why? simple beacuse the path is not correct. When you execute a python file not always its path turn to be the execution path.

Comment: Ok. I get your point. You are absolutely right. But when I distribute the compiled version where do the users store the csv. That path may differ from user to user. Moreover when readcsv('demand.csv') works well when run manually in terminal, why compiled exe fails to locate the csv?

Comment: Thanks, Tzomas. I worked around it using your idea readcsv(os.path.normpath(os.path.realpath('demand.csv'))) without the path. When the execution file is run it looks for the csv files in the users root directory. My issue is resolved. I can ask my users to place the csv files in their root directory. Thanks everyone.